# How to do this query in Laravel 5.4?

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-5

The query is:

```
SELECT * FROM `noticias` WHERE `fecha` in ( select `fecha` from `noticias` group by `fecha` having count(*) > 1)
```

I´m trying in this form:

```
DB::table('noticias')->groupBy('fecha')->having('fecha', '>', 1)->get();
```

But this give me the error:
**SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'conversiones.noticias.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select * from `noticias` group by `fecha` having `fecha` > 1)**

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query would translate to the query builder as follows:

```
DB::table("noticias")
   ->whereIn('fecha', function ($q) {
        return $q->from('noticias')->select("fecha")
                 ->groupBy("fecha")
                 ->having(DB::raw("count(*)"), ">", 1);
   })->get();
```

Comment: Thanks apokryfos! This give me the error: **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::table()** I'm missing something in the controller? I have: `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;`

Comment: I had the wrong parameter name `$query` instead of `$q` and also the wrong function name `table` instead of `from`

Comment: Perfect! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can add ->get() at the end ;)